# Accessing elements in a dynamic object in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic, type-conversion

I have a public function which returns a `dynamic` object. Such `dynamic` object is actually of type `MyObj`  where `MyObj` is a private class of the class which contains the function.

```
public class MyClass
{
        private class MyElement
        {
            public string myString{ get; set; }
        }

        private class MyObj
        {
            public List<MyElement> data { get; set; }
        }

        public dynamic myMethod()
        {
            List<MyElement> myList = (some complex code here).ToList();
            var myObj = new MyObj{ data = myList };

            return myObj;
        }
}
```

Now I need to call such function from **outside the class** like this:

```
var c = new MyClass();
var stuff = c.myMethod();
```

and traverse the element of the output object but as you can see the `stuff` object is shaped as a `dynamic` (look at the return type of the function) so I don'y know the type (is private). How can I explore the array?

Comment: What array? You've got a list, but not an array. You could use `stuff.data[0].mystring` perhaps? Is that what you're looking for? Why are you using dynamic typing anyway? It would also *greatly* help the readability of your question if you'd follow normal .NET naming conventions. Note that you can only access the members of `MyObj` via dynamic typing from places in the code which could see the `MyObj` type. Why is `MyObj` private? (And why aren't you just returning the `List<myElement>`?

Comment: The type could be converted to a JObject or Dictionary and loop the properties keys.

Comment: @JonSkeet I restated the question properly and corrected the typos and syntax errors

Comment: You haven't corrected the naming conventions, or given any motivation for this. We still don't know where you're calling `myMethod()` from (which makes a difference in terms of how you can use the result) or why you're not just returning the list directly.

Comment: @JonSkeet added the class and specified that I'm calling the function from outside such class

Comment: But no reason why you'd want to do all this, or have the nested classes being private in the first place. If you want the caller to see the data within those classes, why make them private?

Comment: @JonSkeet 'cos the caller is passing the object straight to the Ok() function of my .NET WebApi api. The Ok() function will marshal the dynamic object into a json string. I don't need to expose the nested classes as it works fine right now. If you say that the only way to access the content is to make the nested classes public I'll do it. But since the Ok() function can convert the dynamic to a json I think there's is a way to do it even having the nested classes private.

Comment: Well that's presumably because that's using reflection to get at the properties... but you want to get at the properties using dynamic typing, which performs accessibility checks. Why not just make the classes public and avoid dynamic typing entirely? Please edit your question with all the relevant context... I keep asking for more information, but you're giving it out a tiny bit at a time, and mostly in comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer your question, though what you are trying to achieve is a little bit odd.

First thing: you can't access properties of dynamic object if the class of this object is private as metadata of the object is not exposed to you.

The only way is to use reflection:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
var stuff = myClass.myMethod();
var dynamicType = (TypeInfo)stuff.GetType();

var dataProperty = dynamicType.GetProperty("data");
var data = (IEnumerable)dataProperty.GetValue(stuff);

var result = new List<string>();
Type itemType = null;
PropertyInfo myProperty = null;
foreach(var item in data){
    if(itemType == null){
        itemType = item.GetType();
        myProperty = itemType.GetProperty("myString");
    }

    var content = (string)myProperty.GetValue(item);
    result.Add(content);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what @JonSkeet was talking about: probably only reflection can do it. So either I expose the inner classes or use reflection